# Debugging Enhanced Ecommerce in GTM

Tags: transactions, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I am working on a site where enhanced ecommerce is implemented via GTM. However, they are using a transaction tag with a track type of "transaction" which I have read does not work.

However, all transaction data is passing into GA. I assume it is passing in the normal pageview tag but how do I check this? In the preview pane, I still see a "purchase" event passing right after the "pageview."

So my main question is what is a step-by-step way to debug what hit is passing the enhanced ecommerce transaction data? In other implementations I've seen, the normal pageview fires before the ecommerce data is passed and thus does not get sent to GA. Either that isn't the case here, or the transaction tag is somehow capturing the data.

I would also note that enhanced ecommerce specific data is definitely passing (such as product brand).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is data recorded in google analytics is only for standard ecommerce not enhanced ecommerce, because the track type "transaction" is for standard ecommerce
For enhanced ecommerce you would have to enable enhanced ecommerce settings in you pageview tag as mentioned in this doc
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases
http://take.ms/m9Z6u

In GTM it would look like this
http://take.ms/QoUq8

You would also need to enable enhanced e-commerce in GA as well so that you are able to see data in reports.
To learn more about enhanced e-commerce you can read the below article
http://marketlytics.com/blog/what-is-google-analytics-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-reports?rq=enhanced

hope this is helpful for you